# Cognito Create Import Job - insufficient permission

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am trying to import users into Cognito User Pool from CSV file. At User Pool settings, I go to **Users and groups** -> **Import users** -> **Create Import Job**. After filling the form up and clicking **Create job** I am seeing an error saying **You don't have sufficient permission for this operation. Please contact your administrator.**

The IAM user has a policy **AmazonCognitoPowerUser** which includes action **CreateUserImportJob**. It seem it's not enough.

I need a some hint how to configure the user properly to avoid using root account for creating import job (the user could list/start/stop the job, though)

Comment: If you can be granted the managed policy IAMFullAccess, then it should work. I'm still looking into the exact missing permission. It really would be nice if AWS did a better job reporting on which permissions are missing/needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to attach the following permission

```
iam:PassRole
```